# Issue in submitting code to SVN

Tags: svn

while committing my code to SVN I am getting following error

[image]

Please help me how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: Have you made an update before trying to commit?

Comment: not today , update before 3 days

Comment: How is it related to `iphone` and `iphone-sdk-4.0`?

Comment: "before 3 days" --- you need to perform update each time before commit

Comment: now what is the solution does any one know ??

Comment: @zerkms: *you need to perform update each time before commit* is not 100% correct. Only if there were other commits. If there were no other commits in the last three days, the commit would succeed...

Comment: @eckes: yep, indeed. But additional update until he will not get the idea how SVN works will not break anything anyway ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, there were some changes on `ProjectOne/Classes/AESEncryption.m` since your last `update` from the server. Your working copy needs an update before you can commit to the repo.

Do an `update`, in case of conflicts solve them and then try to commit again.